# How to use (if possible) JMeter to load a AWS SQS queue with messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I need to load a SQS queue on the Amazon Web Services to load test an application which consumes the messages from the SQS queue.

Is it possible to load the SQS queue using JMeter?

Are there any better options available to load the SQS queue than using JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to send the messages through [HTTP requests](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequestsArticle.html).

Answer (score 0):

I created JMeter plugin that use AWS SDK to publish events in SNS Standard or FIFO Topic:

https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/awsmeter

You just need AWS IAM user with programmatic access, download JMeter and install awsmeter plugin.

If you have questions or comments let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: 2021-04-28 23:00:32,661 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'Java Request'.
com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials. This is the error i am getting if i pass session token which is the way we authorize