# Using JMeter to load/test Amazon SQS - Not all messages making it through

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, amazon-sqs

I'm attempting to load (with messages) and test my AWS deployed application, which receives messages through SQS and I have been trying to get JMeter to do it, however I can't get JMeter to communicate properly with SQS.

First, I have set SQS to be anonymously accessible, so I don't have to worry about credentials at all:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:843348267853:testQueue/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid1445050222773",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:843348267853:testQueue"
    }
  ]
}
```

To start simple, I am using the JMeter GUI on my Ubuntu machine and created 1 thread group, an HTTP Defaults and 1 HTTP Request.

My Defaults has the following properties:

Server Name: sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Port Number: 80
Parameters: Action=SendMessage
            Version=2011-10-01
Path: /843348267853/testQueue

Then my HTTP Request has the following properties:
Method: POST
Parameters:
MessageBody={"sender":"Sender","event":"started","time":"20150623T214256Z","version":"1.0"
}

Note: I did not check the "Encode?" box for any of the parameters.

My expectation is that it will combine the parameters in the defaults with the parameter in the request, however with the format above, it throws

> org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:80 timed out

If I surround the JSON message in single quotes, it throws:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

I've changed the "Use multipart/form-data for POST" and "Browser-compatible headers" settings and when I examine the Request tab in "View Results Tree", it shows up as:

> POST http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/843348267853/testQueue
>
> POST data:
>   MessageBody=%7B%22sender%22%3A%22Sender%22%2C%22event%22%3A%22started%22%2C%22time%22%3A%2220150623T214256Z%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%7D&Action=SendMessage&Version=2011-10-01
>
> [no cookies]
>
> Request Headers:
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm assuming SQS doesn't like the urlencoding?

I've tried setting various Content-Type headers, escaping the quotes, etc. and none of them worked.

I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that SQS requires key=value formatting, whereas my applications (Logstash and Elasticsearch) are all configured to take JSON, so the JSON needs to be embedded within it.

I've looked at [How to use (if possible) JMeter to load a AWS SQS queue with messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363639/how-to-use-if-possible-jmeter-to-load-a-aws-sqs-queue-with-messages) and there was no specific information to use.  I would also prefer to not have to write my own application and extend JMeter...

Does anyone know how I can use the JMeter GUI to do this?

**EDIT 1** 
At some point in my attempts to get JMeter to properly send messages to Amazon SQS (which gets polled by Logstash which sends the messages to Elasticsearch), I stopped checking Elasticsearch to see if the messages arrived, simply because JMeter was reporting a failure and the messages were initially NOT being received.

I just checked it again and discovered my current JMeter configuration, while reports failures in JMeter, seems to actually send the messages on to SQS.  The new problem is, not all of the messages are getting through.  If JMeter reports it tried 1,000 times, it looks like 100 are getting through...

**HTTP Request Defaults**
- (Same parameters, path, server name)
- Implementation: HttpClient 4
- Protocol: http

**HTTP Request Sampler**
- Parameter of message body, with properly formed JSON (not surrounded by any additional characters and no escaping).
- Method: POST

So, my new question is, is there a reason why not all of the messages would make it through?  Perhaps it's moving too quickly for its own good and it's not actually transmitting all of the messages it says it is?

I have the thread group set to 5 threads, however I selected it should "delay thread creation until needed".  Maybe it's hit some internal race issues?

To test that theory, I inserted a Constant Timer to add a 1 second delay (and again with a 2 second delay) in between each request (should be more than enough time) and let it run for 143 messages.  Of those 143 messages, only 7 made it through....

I then noticed in the "View Results in Table" that all except for a few of the messages would be the same number of bytes (2152) and would have a "connect time" of 0, whereas every several messages would be one that would be 2583 bytes and have a connect time of 11ms or 12ms.  The number of messages that are different than all the others is the number of messages that made it through successfully.

JMeter reports response code/messages for the messages that made it through as follows:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Read timed out
```

Whereas it reports the following for all of the other messages that did not make it through:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connect to sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:80 timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has pretty good support for testing JMS interfaces for messaging systems. You can use the [AWS Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/jmsclient.html) to get a SQS JMS interface.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to write my own application.  Can the GUI use a custom sampler class written in Java?

Comment: You do not have to write your own application to use JMeter. Since JMeter already has support for JMS, you can use the JMS interface provided in the AWS SDK to create a performance test. You just have to define how the test should be run.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information on what is not working ?:
- jmeter.log
- Response you get

From what you show, it appears you're not sending the **request signature **:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html#POSTRequests
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/Query_QueryAuth.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

To do this signing, you can use a JSR223 PreProcessor + Groovy + Java API.

Comment: My understanding is that with my current access policy, it should allow anonymous access (i.e. no signing required).  At any rate, I have made another discovery (with another issue), I am updating my question accordingly.